# Conditionally run tests in Jest

Tags: jestjs, performance-testing

I've been playing around comparing the functional paradigm and the object-oriented paradigm.

As part of this - I'm wanting to do some performance tests.

I have some tests that look like this for now:

```
it("Some long running performance test", () => {
    const result = myFunctionWithLotsOfData();       
});
```

For now, I'm just printing how long this code takes to run (around 5000ms).

I like using Jest for all of the assertions and mocking functionality it gives, and it's live reload, etc.

However, I don't want these tests to all the time, I'd run create a npm script like `npm test:performance`, and only run these tests if an environment variable is present or similar.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: this may be of interest: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/29802/41871

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```js
const itif = (condition) => condition ? it : it.skip;

describe('suite name', () => {
  itif(true)('test name', async () => {
    // Your test
  });
});
```

Comment: Above solution is not working, if I have 2 or more It Blocks in describe. Please let me know, if you have sample solution for this.

Comment: Note that if we use the spread operator, we [don't need a functionfunction call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69396619/740553).

Answer (score 21):

Along the same lines as the accepted answer:

```js
const maybe = process.env.JEST_ALLOW_INTEG ? describe : describe.skip;
maybe('Integration', () => {
    test('some integration test', async () => {
        expect(1).toEqual(1);
        return;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 19):

A small variation on the accepted post, but if we combine Jest's `test.skip(...)` with the kind of blind argument forwarding that modern JS allows thanks to the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), we can get a cleaner solution that conditionally runs tests, while letting Jest know it skipped something "the official way", without needing a "functionfunction" call:

```js
const testIf = (condition, ...args) =>
  condition ? test(...args) : test.skip(...args);

describe(`a mix of tests and conditional tests`, () => {
  test(`this will always run`, () => {
    expect("1").toBe("1");
  });

  testIf(Math.random() > 0.5, `this will only run half the time`, () => {
    expect("2").toBe("2");
  });
});
```

or here's the typescript version

```js
const testIf = (condition: boolean, ...args: Parameters<typeof test>) =>
  condition ? test(...args) : test.skip(...args);
```

Half the time this will run as:

```
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.451 s, estimated 1 s
```

And half the time it will show:

```
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 skipped, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.354 s, estimated 1 s
```

But to cover the part that no one seems to have included in their answers, we can use this to skip over long-running tests by combining it with "looking at `process.argv` for a runtime flag":

```js
const runLong = process.argv.includes(`--run-long`);

const testIf = (condition, ...args) =>
  condition ? test(...args) : test.skip(...args);

describe(`Run tests, and long tests only if told to`, () => {

  // ...

  testIf(runLong, `Some long-running test, skip if --run-long is not set`, () => {
    // a test that runs for a long time here
  });
});
```

And then we can just put that runtime flag in our npm script. However, we need to make sure to forward that flag on to our script, rather than to jest, or to npm:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  ...
  "test": "jest somedir",
  "test:long": "npm run test -- -- --run-long",
  ...
},
...
```

This looks kind of weird, and it *is* kind of weird, but it's a consequence of how argument forwarding works for npm scripts:

1. The first `--` tells *npm* that it needs to forward what follows, rather than interpreting that flag itself (in effect: this makes npm run `jest somedir -- --run-long`).
2. The second `--` tells *jest* that it needs to forward what follows, instead of considering it a runtime flag for itself, so that *our script* gets to see it in its `process.argv` list (so that we call `ourscript --run-long`).

A common mistake is to forget that second `--`, which would lead to a fun error that doesn't tell you that just forgot two dashes, and no tests running at all.

Comment: If you want to pass arguments to jest like in this answer, you need to specify a folder. You cannot use `"test:long": "jest -- --run-long"`, you need `"test:long": "jest somedir -- --run-long"`.

Comment: Was that not obvious enough from the post's two scripts, and the explanation of how `--` falls through:? `npm run test:long` runs `npm run test -- -- --run-long`, which runs `jest somedir -- --run-long`, so that `jest` runs on `somedir` while forwarding `--run-long` so that it ends up in `process.args`. The code in the post pretty clearly calls jest with a directory as its target.

Comment: No, that was not obvious to me. I usually run my tests with only `jest`, and when trying to apply your answer to my workflow that didn't work. I think you got a nice solution, I just wanted to give a hint to others who are trying to do the same as me.

Comment: This solution as it stands does not allow for failing async tests that throw in jest, and will throw an `ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION` error. Using the `const itif = (cond) => cond ? it : it.skip` handles it appropriately.

Comment: Uh... why would your _tests_ throw? Even if you _code_ can throw, your tests should never throw: fix your code inside your test so that you're catching throws your know they might happen, and can fail the test accordingly. You should never have test in which calls that can throw "just throw".

Comment: If you change your condition to `process.env.npm_lifecycle_event==="test:long"` then you don't need any argument passing. You can just have ` "test:long": "jest somedir" in your ` in your package.json

Comment: Somewhat hacky, so not something I'd advocate even if it works for you.

Comment: @TomHoward looks like you double-posted you comment, so you'll want to delete one of them =)

Answer (score 5):

Here is one solution, create `itif` function so that we can run the unit tests based on some conditions.

For example, the `itif` function:

```js
export const itif = (name: string, condition: () => boolean | Promise<boolean>, cb) => {
  it(name, async done => {
    if (await condition()) {
      cb(done);
    } else {
      console.warn(`[skipped]: ${name}`);
      done();
    }
  });
};
```

The unit tests:

```js
describe('test suites', () => {
  itif(
    'functional-approach-2 perforance test',
    async () => process.env.PERFORMANCE_TEST === 'true',
    done => {
      console.info('Functional Approach 2 Performance Test');
      const t0 = Date.now();
      const m0 = getMemory();
      const li0 = instantiateFanRecursive(20, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1);
      const r0 = getDrawablesFromLineInstances(li0);
      printMemory(getMemory() - m0);
      console.info(`Length: ${r0.length}`);
      console.info(`Time Taken: ${Date.now() - t0}ms`);
      done();
    }
  );
});
```

Run your unit test when the value of `process.env.PERFORMANCE_TEST` environment variable equal `'true'`, the result:

```sh
PERFORMANCE_TEST=true npm t -- /Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/58264344/index.spec.t

> jest-codelab@1.0.0 test /Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab
> jest --detectOpenHandles "/Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/58264344/index.spec.ts"

 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58264344/index.spec.ts
  test suites
    ✓ functional-approach-2 perforance test (18ms)

  console.info src/stackoverflow/58264344/index.spec.ts:22
    Functional Approach 2 Performance Test

  console.log src/stackoverflow/58264344/index.spec.ts:4
    0

  console.info src/stackoverflow/58264344/index.spec.ts:28
    Length: 0

  console.info src/stackoverflow/58264344/index.spec.ts:29
    Time Taken: 5ms

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.67s, estimated 9s
```

Do not run the unit test when the value of `process.env.PERFORMANCE_TEST` environment variable is not set:

```sh
npm t -- /Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/58264344/index.spec.ts

> jest-codelab@1.0.0 test /Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab
> jest --detectOpenHandles "/Users/elsa/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/58264344/index.spec.ts"

 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58264344/index.spec.ts
  test suites
    ✓ functional-approach-2 perforance test (11ms)

  console.warn src/stackoverflow/58264344/index.spec.ts:11
    [skipped]: functional-approach-2 perforance test

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.758s, estimated 5s
```